# How do I get the error code and description from a Savon::SOAPFault?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I can see in the Savon log that my SOAP faults contain XML like this:

```
<errorCode>666</errorCode><errorDescription>some evil error</errorDescription>
```

Does anyone know how to parse the error code and description out of the response? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I've tried everything, and I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the only way I was able to do this was by disabling Savon exceptions:

```
Savon::Response.raise_errors = false
```

After doing this, I had to check response.soap_fault? after each SOAP call to see if there was an error. Then I could access the error details using response.to_hash.

Comment: FYI: this problem should be fixed with Savon v0.8.0

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
def your_method(credentials)
  # your client call here
rescue Savon::SOAPFault => error
  fault_code = error.to_hash[:fault][:faultcode]
  raise CustomError, fault_code
end
```

Got this solution from `Savon` [documentation](http://savonrb.com/version2/errors.html).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this patch:

```
module Savon
  class SOAPFault

    def soap_error_code
      fault = nori.find(to_hash, 'Fault')
      if nori.find(fault, 'faultcode')
        nori.find(fault, 'faultcode').to_i
      elsif nori.find(fault, 'Code')
        nori.find(fault, 'Code', 'Value').to_i
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Then in controller:

```
begin
 # do something
rescue Savon::SOAPFault => e
  raise CustomError, e.soap_error_code
end
```